# Audio ContentProvider and ID3 tags editing

Tags: android, audio, metadata, android-contentprovider

How **Content Provider** get audio metadata? If i have edited MP3 file **ID3** tags, will be provider refresh himself with new data or i need manually edit data in him ? And if i edit tags for some song in provider , will be song **ID3** tags updated?